# SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008, ssrs

Will SQL Server 2008 Reporting services work if it is install on Windows 2003?

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runs fine, I have one in production (SSRS 2008, not R2) and have had no problems related to the server OS.

Comment: And just to confirm this I have a box in production that is using SQL server 2008R2 and running on windows server 2003 with no problems